# Build matrix with combinations of pairs between 2 groups in R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I have 2 sets of points : one containing 8 start points and the other with 8 final points. My objective is to build a matrix with all pairs of two couples (start1, end1) & (start2, end2).
The first group with 8 start points is `(pt1, ... pt8)` and the end group is `(pt9, ... pt16)`.
I want to build the matrix with all pairs of couple of points between the 2 groups like this :

```
[pt1 pt9 pt2 pt10
 pt3 pt11 pt4 pt12
 pt5 pt13 pt6 pt14
 ...
#and then crossed pairs
 pt1 pt10 pt2 pt9
 etc... ]
```

First and third columns containing the start points of the 2 couples and second and fourth with the end points associated. I tried with circular permutations but I don't get all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand.grid` to create all possible pairs and then use `expand.grid` again to generate all permutation of pairs as follows:

```
s <- 1:8
e <- 9:16
pairCombi <- expand.grid(s,e)
ix <- expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(pairCombi)), seq_len(nrow(pairCombi)))
ans <- as.data.frame(t(apply(ix[ix$Var1 != ix$Var2, ], 1L, function(n) {
    c(unlist(pairCombi[n[1L],]), unlist(pairCombi[n[2L],]))
})))
colnames(ans) <- paste0("Var", seq_len(ncol(ans)))
```